# Spotifre create button to log off using scripts

Tags: python, analytics, visualization, spotfire

I am trying to create a button in a text area in Spotfire to log off when clicked.

So basically I want to make a "sign off" button when running the Spotfire report in a web browser environment. And I think this needs to be done with scripts but I don't know how to proceed.

Can anyone share some insights on if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

in a text area create

```
<button id='logout'>Log Out</button>
```

add javascript:

```
 $(logout).button().on('click',function(){
    top.location="/SpotfireWeb/LoggedOut.aspx?logoutByUser=True"
 })
```